# Batch Aggregation in Stepfunction Express

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-step-functions

I have a AWS Stepfunction that is processing items in a external call. To increase the efficiency of the downstream system i would like to batch single executions into one and after processing of the batch transform the batch into single items again. I know this is not possible by default, but is there a clever way, maybe with DynamoDb or another tool to batch items ?